# Who is behind 'Community' and the bumping of questions to 'homepage'?

Tags: support

One of my older questions has been 'bumped to homepage' by 'Community'.

Who actually initiates this process ? Is it something I can participate in or is it exclusive to Moderators ?

And what, or where, is the 'homepage'. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is spelled out in detail in the [Community user's profile page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). These is nothing users or moderators can control about this, it's programmed into the system as a robot that takes actions based on certain conditions.

The homepage is, um, [the home page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/). It's where you first land when you come to the domain and linked as "home" in the sidebar.